# git not cloning my laravel public folder

Tags: github, laravel

I pushed my laravel application to github and everything went well. However, now I'm trying to clone my laravel application to work on it on a different computer but when I clone my repository I don't get my public folder. The public folder exists in my github repository. I checked gitignore and public folder is not listed there. Anybody has any idea?

Comment: Is your github repo public? If posting it here could be a good clue.

Comment: Maybe is hidden? Is it possible? Check `ls -a` on linux for sure.

Comment: It's not hidden. I viewed the hidden files and public folder is not one of them.